# Show-stopper Eclipse Helios install problems under OSX (10.6) 64bit

Tags: eclipse, macos, installation, eclipse-3.6

I thought I'd give Helios a try, so I grabbed the latest Java EE install from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliosr.  Note, both OSX 32bit and 64bit exhibit the same symptoms.

So from a fresh install I run Helios (it launches fine), then the problem comes when I try running an upgrade.  I keep getting these two errors errors:

1. Artifact not found: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/compositeContent.jar.
   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/compositeContent.jar
2. No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios.

These are my (default) update sites:

1. Helios   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios Enabled
2. Mylyn for Eclipse Helios http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/helios Enabled
3. The Eclipse Project Updates http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6 Enabled
4. The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) software repository http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios Enabled
5. http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/e3.4 Disabled
   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/extras Disabled

Note, I'm not behind any firewalls/proxies etc, no nothing weird with network connectivity.

I've searched all over the place and there are others with the same problem, with no solution that I could find.

Has anyone else run into these issues?

**UPDATE 1**:
Notes:

1. I'm not behind a proxy.
2. I've tried the Java EE, but also bare bones Eclipse 3.6.1.
3. I've tried different mirrors (including the main site),
4. I've tried SpingSource's version.
5. I've tried exporting the update sites to XML, deleting them and reimporting them.
6. I even tried adding forward slashes to the ends of site names.
7. I've made sure I have full write permissions for the eclipse folder, and have even placed it on my desktop.

I mention all of these seemingly odd behaviours because these are suggestions I've read around the web on this problem, which many people are having.

Once last interesting point I've just tried, is to download the "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/compositeContent.jar" directly in the browser.  It redirects to "http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/eclipse/releases/helios/compositeContent.jar" with a 403 forbidden. :\ *It seems as though system is finding a mirror, but perhaps the mirror is broken?  Also note, I'm in Australia, so Georgia Tech is nowhere near me ;)*

Just as I was writing this, I tried one last idea.  I discovered "Pulse" by Genuitec, which is a Eclipse install manager.  I gave it a shot, and it worked.  The site it uses for updates is:

"[url=http://eclipse.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/aux/eclipse-mirror/releases/helios]  http://eclipse.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/aux/eclipse-mirr or/releases/helios[/url]"

So, I've wasted enough time on this now.  I'd create a bug in Eclipse Bugzilla, but there are already entries with no solution.

**UPDATE 2**:
Ok, from a fresh install, if I disable:

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/

and add Pulse's update site:

http://eclipse.poweredbypulse.com/downloads/aux/eclipse-mirror/releases/helios/

I don't get any errors.  I really think it's to do with the automatic mirrored update site.  Is this possible?

Here is a screenshot of my update sites now:

[image]

Regards,

Shane

Comment: According to [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329923) the problem is with how they set up the automatic mirrored site, as you suspected. This is crazy! Setting up Helios updating is a  nightmare. Just for this reason, switching back to Galileo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See update 2 in the question.

Shane

Comment: please add the solution as answer rather than an update (even if it's your own) next time

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had the same issue on Windows XP 64bits laptop an Fresh Helios 64bits download, however your workaround works for me.